# Web API List<T> returns xml but IEnumerable<T> returns json. Why?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-webapi

The questions kinda says it all, but I am using the exact same javascript to call two web api endpoints. One returns an IEnumerable and the response is JSON. The other returns List and the response is XML. When I change the List to an IEnumerable the response becomes json.
If I add `.AsEnumerable()` to the List, I still get XML.

It's a .Net6 web app that I am in the process of converting from .Net Framework 4.7

This returns XML (in .Net6, but returns json in .Net Framework 4.7):

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("listall")]
public IActionResult ListAll()
{
    using (var websiteClientService = new WebsiteClientService())
    {
        List<WebsiteClientListItem> websiteClientResults = websiteClientService.ListAll().ToList();
        websiteClientResults.Insert(0, new WebsiteClientListItem() { Name = "Default Website", Id = -1 });
        return Ok(websiteClientResults);
    }
}
```

This also returns XML

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("listall")]
public IActionResult ListAll()
{
    using (var websiteClientService = new WebsiteClientService())
    {
        List<WebsiteClientListItem> websiteClientResults = websiteClientService.ListAll().ToList();
        websiteClientResults.Insert(0, new WebsiteClientListItem() { Name = "Default Website", Id = -1 });
        return Ok(websiteClientResults.AsEnumerable()); // Added .AsEnumerable()
    }
}
```

but this returns json:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("listall")]
public IActionResult ListAll()
{
    using (var websiteClientService = new WebsiteClientService())
    {
        IEnumerable<WebsiteClientListItem> websiteClientResults = websiteClientService.ListAll();
        // websiteClientResults.Insert(0, new WebsiteClientListItem() { Name = "Default Website", Id = -1 });
        return Ok(websiteClientResults);
    }
}
```

I have tried specifying the contentType in the ajax call, but that had no effect.

When I added the `SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter` in `Program.cs` the `List<T>` returns json.

```
options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter(new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerDefaults.Web)));
options.OutputFormatters.Insert(1, new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
```

So why would a `List<T>` default to XML and `IEnumerable<T>` default to json regardless of the `OutputFormatters`?

Comment: What do the requests look like. The `Accept` header specifies what format the request wants to see the the response

Comment: @Flydog57 both requests are identical. The Accept header on both calls is `Accept: */*`. Literally the only different on the client side is the url

Comment: Have you tried this attribute [Produces("application/json")] on your action?

Comment: You can change things to force a specific format, sure, but the question is about why the return type, as the only difference, causes serialization in an entirely different format.

Comment: It usually be decided based on your client `Accept header` they sends.  If you return a serializable object, WebAPI will automatically send JSON or XML. But if you always would like to return json result you could configure it by using [`JsonSerializerOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-systemtextjson-based-formatters-2) within your program.cs file

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but as stated, the `Accept` header was the same in both cases

Comment: Then you can specify that on your `JsonSerializerOptions` to strictly implement json response.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I don't want the response to be limited to Json. It should be determined by the request headers

Comment: If you set your request header does it generates your expected results? It should be I guess.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron It does not. That's the whole reason for my question